# I'm not sure how to add this image to the screen (turtle)

Tags: python, python-turtle

I entered this turtle code to print a cookie on the screen, but the cookie doesn't actually show up.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Cookie Clicker")
wn.bgcolor("black")

wn.mainloop()

cookie = "cookie.gif"
turtle.register_shape(cookie)
turtle.shape(cookie)
```

Anyone know how to fix this? By the way I'm using PyCharm and 'cookie.gif' is in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't an animated GIF, the problem is you've put `wn.mainloop()` in the wrong place in your code.  Generally, it's the last thing you do in a turtle program:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

cookie = "cookie.gif"

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Cookie Clicker")
screen.bgcolor('black')

screen.register_shape(cookie)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape(cookie)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Uhh this code doesn't work. I'm using a png file btw.

Comment: @ScroppySucksAtCoding, twice in your post you said GIF, not PNG, both in text and code.  PNG files may or may not work depending how up to date your Python and Tk are.  I tested the above code with a GIF file, as specified, and it works fine.